# retry deadlocks in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

i try to implement a retry strategy on deadlock in mysql and nodej, buy i lack some information about transaction commit.

what i try to do is, if i get an err dead lock i do commit agian after a short dealy.

do i need to run all the previos queries agian or recommit is just enough?

```
 connection.commitTransaction = function () {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const commit = () => {
                    connection.commit(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("err.code", err.code);
                            if (err.code === 'ER_LOCK_DEADLOCK') {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    commit();
                                }, 50);
                                return
                            }
                            return connection.rollback(function () {
                                connection.end();
                                reject(err);
                            });
                        }
                        connection.end();
                        resolve();
                    });
                };
                commit();
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transactions gets rolled back, so you need to execute the queries again.

Actually, you probably have to run *different* queries again (or at least check if they are still valid), e.g. by applying the logic again that let to those specific queries.

A deadlock usually means that you based (or could have based) the decision to execute a specific query (with these specific values) on data that has (or could have been) changed by another transaction, so the queries you just ran might not be valid anymore. Otherwise, MySQL would probably have a function to just repeat the queries for you.